# Laravel dynamic database connection

Tags: php, laravel

I have a website at work to handle cases.

My first page is a table with all my cases based on my first database with all cases in a table.

When I select a case, I change my mysql connection to the name of the case.

So for example, I'm connect to Cases DB and when I click on case A001, I change my DB to A001.

How can I handle it with laravel ? I rode that connections must be inside .env or database.config but I don't know all the cases name and there will be a lot !

How can I switch DB based on db's name ?

Thank

Edit for Erkan Özkök :

I tried your code inside my controler@table but it isn't working :

```
// $lots = Lot::on($lot_id)->first();
            $connection_name = 'A002';

            //firstly, define configurations
            Config::set('database.connections.' . $connection_name, array(
                    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'driver'    => 'mysql',
                    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', $connection_name),
                    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
                    'port'      => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
                    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
                    'charset'   => 'utf8mb4',
                    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
                    'prefix'    => '',
                    'strict'    => true,
            ));

            //then activate the connection.
            Config::set('database.default', $connection_name);
```

Bonus question : is it possible to etablish a connection at some point and use it whatever function I use or must I initialize the connection each time ?

Comment: I don't know which library you are using. But PDO doesn't require database name in the connection string. You simply can refer to it like database1.table1 or database2.table1

Comment: Are the tables the same in every database?  Sounds like an odd design.   Are you using Eloquent Models or just the Query Builder for Laravel?

Comment: @Devon yes tables are the same, I separated because there's a lot of data for each case. What other options do I have ?

Comment: @frz3993 so in laravel how can I select/insert/update with DB name ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a case_id foreign key in your tables instead of separate databases?

Comment: @Devon separates DB aren't better than a lot of data inside one ? I did that to save DB zip inside my case folder too

Comment: To me no, separate databases would be incredibly hard to maintain and you'd have a much harder time forming relationships and running reports.

Comment: I'm no familiar with laravel but I found something that might be useful to you here https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#accessing-connections

Comment: @frz3993 yes I saw that but it seems that the DB name must be hard coded inside configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can change your db connection dynamically.

```
    $connection_name = 'A001';

    //firstly, define configurations
    Config::set('database.connections.' . $connection_name, array(
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'database'  => $connection_name,
            'username'  => 'root',
            'port'      => '3306',
            'password'  => '',
            'charset'   => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => true,
    ));

    //then activate the connection.
    Config::set('database.default', $connection_name);
```

Comment: I tried on my controller but it doesn't work. Still connect to default db.

Comment: I use exactly your code on my controler. I have a function call table to return bdd data to my data via ajax. I updated my question.

Comment: i updated my code,  it is about env('DB_DATABASE', $connection_name)  part.

Comment: Seems to work now ! Is it possible to set this  connection when I go to a part of my site (let's say /case/A001) without having to create connection for each function ?